# Updating a column that is within a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple view set in place which joins 3 different tables and displays data within my program. I noticed however, that  I can update columns from the table PRODCODE like so:

```
update PRODCODE_VW set MAXGH = 5.00 where ORIGREC = 114406 --RETURNS 1 UPDATED
```

And it will update 1 record. However, when I do an update on ExpectedLevels, it will update 0 rows. I'm assuming this is because it is left joined. Is there a way to get around this by only altering the way the view is set up and not the update statement?

```
update PRODCODE_VW set EMIN = 5.00 where ORIGREC = 114406 --RETURNS 0 UPDATED
```

This is the view I have set in place:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
       WHERE  TABLE_NAME = N'PRODCODE_vw')
    DROP VIEW PRODCODE_vw
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.PRODCODE_vw
AS 
SELECT PRODCODE.STUFF,PRODCODE.ORIGREC,PRODCODE.PRODCODE,PRODCODE.PRODNAM,
C1JMASTER.C1JTYPE, EXPECTEDLEVELS.EMIN, EXPECTEDLEVELS.EMAX
FROM PRODCODE (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN C1JMASTER (NOLOCK) 
    ON PRODCODE.c1jcode = C1JMASTER.c1jcode 
    LEFT JOIN EXPECTEDLEVELS 
    ON PRODCODE.PRODCODE = EXPECTEDLEVELS.PRODCODE

GO
```

Comment: You really should avoid NoLock.  It is poorly named and instructs SQL Server to ignore existing locks held by other transaction, meaning you may read uncommitted data.  A query with NoLock hints will still request locks on the objects needed to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select ORIGREC = 114406 from the view, is there any value for EMIN, or it is null?  Most likely, the ORIGREC 114406 does not have a matching record in the left joined table.  Your update statement effectively filters on `WHERE ORIGREC = 114406 AND PRODCODE.PRODCODE = EXPECTEDLEVELS.PRODCODE`

You can target the left joined tables as long as your affected columns are all sourced from the same table in the view.  However, if the left join would not return a EXPECTEDLEVELS row for the ORIGREC, your rows updated will be zero, because there is no matching row in the target table.